# db2 table inactive after a patch

Tags: database, db2

I ran the following db2 script with no problem on my terminal. but when I try to access the actual front end page involved with this table I get the error (code **57016**) that indicates the table is inactive. I restarted the db2 but still this issue is happening.

Can anyone please help me out here

```
alter table CUSTOMER alter column Delivery set default 0! 
alter table CUSTOMER alter column Delivery set not null! 

alter table CUSTOMER add constraint pref_ck4 check (Delivery between 0 and 1)!

commit!
quit!
```

and the rollback was:

```
alter table CUSTOMER alter Delivery drop DEFAULT!
alter table CUSTOMER alter COLUMN Delivery drop NOT NULL!

alter table CUSTOMER drop constraint pref_ck4!

reorg table CUSTOMER!

commit!
quit!
```

The error I receive:

```
UncategorisedDatabaseException: Query=[SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID = ?], database       vendor error message is: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -668, SQLSTATE: 57016, SQLERRMC: 7;CUSTOMER, UncategorisedDatabaseException errorCode = -668

db2 => ? 57016

SQLSTATE 57016: The table cannot be accessed, because it is inactive.
```

Comment: And how is this related to Java?

Comment: usually Java devs are more into db2 stuff than others!

Comment: Can you please add some relevant info ?

Comment: I added the error details, please let me know what else would be helpful to add thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's best to look at SQLCODE and SQLERRMC to understand the specific error.  SQLSTATE doesn't uniquely identify an error.

SQLCODE `-668` is SQL0668N;  SQLERRMC (`7;CUSTOMER`) indicates that it's due to reason code 7 on the CUSTOMER table.

To look up [this error](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00668n.html) you can use a handy reference from a DB2 client:

```
$ db2 "? sql0668n"


SQL0668N  Operation not allowed for reason code "<reason-code>" on table
      "<table-name>".

Explanation: 

Access to table "<table-name>" is restricted. The cause is based on the
following reason codes "<reason-code>": 

[...]

7        
         The table is in the reorg pending state. This can occur after
         an ALTER TABLE statement containing a REORG-recommended
         operation.

[...]

User response:

[...]

7        
         Reorganize the table using the REORG TABLE command.

         For a table in the reorg pending state, note that the following
         clauses are not allowed when reorganizing the table:

         *  The INPLACE REORG TABLE clause
         *  The ON DATA PARTITION clause for a partitioned table when
            table has nonpartitioned indexes defined on the table
```

The solution is to run `REORG` on your table.